# Performance of Queue? Expecting to have heavy RAM usage but instead I get heavy CPU usage

Tags: c#, performance, data-structures

Let's say I am receiving a signal at a variable rate fluctuating between 50 and 200 times per second. I want to store the timestamp of each signal I received into a queue, so I can remove it from the queue when the signal was received more than 1 week ago.

```
public Queue<long> myQueue = new Queue<long>();

public OnSignalReceived()
{
    myQueue.Enqueue(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks);
    PurgeOldSignals();
}

public void PurgeOldSignals()
{
    while (myQueue.Count > 0 && myQueue.Peek() < DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7).Ticks)
    {
        myQueue.Dequeue();
    }
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? This is my implementation and I was expecting to take advantage of using a lot of memory (because let's say an average of 100 signals per second, it means the queue will hold about 60 millions items(!) before starting to purge items) in exchange of having computational performance because of the O(1) time to `Enqueue()` and `Dequeue()`.

After testing however, I noticed that the bottleneck is the CPU and not the RAM. In fact, the RAM barely gets eaten up, but the CPU usage never ceases to increase. Here is the result after about 16 hours of running (clearly far away from my 7 days objective)

[image]

Any suggestions to optimize this?

EDIT 1:

In fact, the whole purpose of this is just to know at any time how many signals I got in the last week (precise to the actual second). Maybe there is a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Just from a glance, you said that there will be 100 signals per second (one per 10 milliseconds). The computer should handle the configuration of memory at a nanosecond speed, so de-queuing 100 signals will take a mere 100 ns (not even a microsecond). What this means is that the processor is dealing with the while loop at an aggressive rate, and as a result the memory is being constrained from growing wildly.

Comment: Simplest thing to do would probably be to throttle the cleanup. Make it only fire once every second or something to that effect.

Comment: Perhaps [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx) would be more suitable with reader+writer threads?

Comment: Why do you want to hold **7 days** worth of data (whatever millions that is) in memory **before you start to process them**?

Comment: What happens if you create the queue with an initial capacity of your expected max capacity? As it is, you'll do a lot of growing, which gets increasingly more expensive.

Comment: OP isn't even storing the signal, just the time it was received. Doesn't make sense to me. Unless the periodicity is what's being studied and the actual signal information doesn't matter.

Comment: @hatchet I do not know the expected max capacity (I say it's averaging 50-200 per second but I cannot assume it, it might well go off to 1000/s for a whole day even if almost unprobable)

Comment: what's the point of `myQueue.Count >0` ? your having heaps of data there all the time :) . (but for the first check, but then you can deal with it at a different point)

Comment: At any rate, pull the date calculation out of the loop since it really only needs to be evaluated once: `long threshold = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7).Ticks; while (myQueue.Peek() < threshold) myQueue.Dequeue();`

Comment: So everything what is needed it to answer the question: "How many events were there in the last 3600*24*7 seconds"? Am I right?

Comment: @AntonínLejsek Yes that would be correct

Comment: It seems unlikely that the code you posted is causing that CPU usage. I suspect that if you remove the `PurgeOldSignals` method, you'll still see the high CPU usage. Also, memory won't increase by all that much. You're only talking about 30 megabytes for the array to hold 16 hours' worth of signals.

Comment: Correction: About 50 megabytes to hold the data for 16 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For given task I would make circular queue of 3600*24*7 integers. Every integer would mean number of events in that second (for every second in one week). It would only need few megabytes. On measured event the integer corresponding to actual second (=now) would increment. It would be convenient to have sum of all items in the array and just update it on change to get it fast.

```
public class History
{
    protected int eventCount = 0;
    protected int[] array;
    protected readonly int _intervalLength_ms;
    long actualTime = 0;
    int actIndex = 0;

    public History(int intervalLength_ms, int numberOfIntervals)
    {
        _intervalLength_ms = intervalLength_ms;
        array = new int[numberOfIntervals];
    }

    public int EventCount
    {
        get
        {
            Update();
            return eventCount;
        }
    }

    public void InsertEvent()
    {
        Update();
        array[actIndex]++;
        eventCount++;
    }

    protected void Update()
    {
        long newTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks / 10000 / _intervalLength_ms;

        while (newTime > actualTime && eventCount > 0)
        {
            actualTime++;
            actIndex++;
            if (actIndex >= array.Length)
            {
                actIndex = 0;
            }
            eventCount -= array[actIndex];
            array[actIndex] = 0;
        }

        if (newTime > actualTime)
        {
            actualTime = newTime;
            actIndex = (int)(actualTime % array.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

It would be constructed with parameters `new History(1000, 3600*24*7)`.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, will look into it :)

Answer (score -1):

I see two issues:

1. (minor) but DateTime.Now is considerably more expensive then DateTime.UTCNow, so you might want to bring that out of the loop instead of doing it 60 million times.
2. (major) you are looping through millions of items every time you get a signal. If you only want to purge it by 7 days old signals, you should only run your purge once a day.

Comment: Speed isn't the only reason the OP should use `UTCNow'. Issues related to changes to and from daylight savings is another.

Comment: re 2: because he might want the last 7 days data at any point ? doing it once a day will have a different behavior.

Comment: Thanks, this example was pseudo-ish code I got off the top of my head...indeed I am using DateTime.UtcNow. For point #2, I don't see how I loop through the whole queue each time? I am only dequeuing until I get to a timestamp greater than 1 week ago from my perspective. Also I cannot run it only once a day because I need the queue to be always up-to-date, not refresh it once a day

Comment: @ibiza Not the whole queue, but still checking millions because at an average rate of 100 signals per second, it takes less than a day to rack up a million records. And you're looping through **7 days** of records.

Comment: @itsme86 ? it's a queue. FIFO. so, every time he adds, he's looking at the ones at the BACK ...

Comment: He's not looping through millions of signals, but rather just those at the front of the queue that are older than 7 days. And in this test *none* of them are older than 7 days, so the loop is only looking at one of them.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect the reason this is slow is because of this

> If Count already equals the capacity, the capacity of the Queue is
>   increased by automatically reallocating the internal array, and the
>   existing elements are copied to the new array before the new element
>   is added.
>
> If Count is less than the capacity of the internal array,
>   this method is an O(1) operation. If the internal array needs to be
>   reallocated to accommodate the new element, this method becomes an
>   O(n) operation, where n is Count.

From the MSDN documentation on `Queue<T>.Enqueue()` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t249c2y7(v=vs.110).aspx). The CPU usage is increasing proprtional to `n` because you are performing an O(n) operation on `myQueue`.

The solution then is to allocate as much memory as you want this program to use immediately, by calling `var myQueue = new Queue<long>(n);` and then your code will make the desired change and switch to high memory usage instead of CPU usage.

Comment: The default capacity is 32, and it will double each time it needs to grow.

Comment: I think it might be that...will do some more testing, thanks!

Comment: @hatchet true, although from the given code it is the only possible candidate, I wonder if the problem lies elsewhere...

Comment: @ibiza are you sure your CPU problem is with the queue implementation and not somewhere else in your program? What happens if your program dies as well? Keeping this all in memory isn't ideal unless you don't care about losing the data if the program closes/crashes.

Comment: If that were the problem, you'd see spikes in the CPU usage, not continual increase. The queue doubles in size with each reallocation. At 100 signals per second, in 16 hours he would have generated about 5.8 million signals. The next higher power of 2 is 2^23, or 8.4 million. So if the queue starts at 32 items (2^5), then at most there would have been 18 reallocations over 16 hours. Those would show as spikes, not continually increasing CPU usage.

Comment: @JimMischel This is a hour by hour chart, maybe the spikes are not shown because they happened within an hour? (ie. in a bar there was a spike and after the reallocation, the CPU went back to 'normal', still increasing its usage as the queue gets larger)

Comment: @ibiza: True enough, except that there's nothing in the posted code that would cause that kind of CPU usage.